# Resume video playback after pause in JavaScript/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to pause a video and then resume the playback. But I presume I somehow need to clear the pause function? I've tried iterations of  myVideo.play() and I can get it to play but only for short bursts. Any help would be much welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Html5 Video Test </title> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body> <
<div style="text-align:center">

  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>

  <video id="video1" width="420" autoplay>

    <source src="test.mov" type="video/mov">
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div>

<script>


var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 1 * 2) {
        this.pause();
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your event listener to only fire once (so when you next play the video, it doesn't just immediately get paused again). If so, give this a shot:

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");

// Give this function a name so we can refer to it later.
function pauseOnce() {
   if (this.currentTime >= 1 * 2) {
       this.pause();

       // Our work is done. Remove the event listener. (We need a reference to
       // the function here.)
       this.removeEventListener("timeupdate", pauseOnce);
   }
}

myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", pauseOnce);
```

Comment: Thanks, after a little bit of fiddling I aha'd and realised I obviously need to add a function that resumes the video again. I realise that this is probably obvious to many, but as I've hunted around to an answer on how to pause / resume an html5 video I'm adding this is as a follow up comment. After @smarx code above, add the following function with an associated html button.

`function resume(){
  vid.play(); 
}`